# Using EventEmitter as Input() in Angular Component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have 2 components b,c on the same level contained in a

```
a
 b
 c
```

c has raises events using EventEmitter eC in Output() that I want to consume in b.
As I cannot "directly" feed that to b, I "redirected" those events by creating another EventEmitter eA that lives in a, that just replays incoming events eC. Then I pass this EventEmitter as an Input() to b:

```
//b
  @Input() public reloadRequested: EventEmitter<void>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadRequested.subscribe(() => {
...
    });
  }
```

Is there anything wrong this approach? I was wondering because I basically did not find anything during my online researches.
How would you do this otherwise?

**UPDATE:**
I don't want to pass data to a component but an event.
Using the Input() Decorator, referencing an EventEmitter of the parent component, seems to be the obvious way for me.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of doing this is, with keeping the rest of the setup the same (component C emits events, parent A handles the events), is: patch values (not event emitter/observable) as input to component B, and in B either use `ngOnChanges` hook or a setter input:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.someInput) {
// do stuff with this.someInput
    }
}
```

or

```
@Input set() someInput (value: any) {
// do stuff with `value`
}
```

MAJOR EDIT: but considering that C isn't emitting any *values* that we care about, we care only about the fact of emission itself, this isn't the right pattern. Your approach with observable input is sound, just a small improvement: the parent doesn't actually have to do anything, certainly not create another observable. All the necessary building blocks are there, just glue them together in the template:

```
<app-c #thatButton></app-c>
<app-b [foo$]="thatButton.foo"></app-b>
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-changes-utvl61?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts

Comment: okay so instead of replaying events of C using another eventemitter in A you would change input data of B. okay I can see how this works but this doesn't look elegant to me. I still wonder how my approach isn't the obvious one to be honest?

Comment: ... mapping an event<void> to input data is even more confusing since you would need to map it to a boolean which does not represent an event<void> very well.

Comment: @ybother OK, if C's emissions are void, that would not be the good approach (still could make it work, but it would be hacky). Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for showing me how to "glue them" together. I really was worried about that redirecting of events instead of directly using them

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> Use in components with the @Output directive to emit custom events synchronously or asynchronously, and register handlers for those events by subscribing to an instance. [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

also

> Extends RxJS Subject for Angular by adding the emit() method. [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#usage-notes)

So it really looks like the are just a Subject with only one purpose: Output data from a component so i would use them just for this.

I usually subscribe the eventEmitter in the parent, store the data in a variable and send it to the Input of the other child components.

Everything should refresh automatically.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't want to send data to a component but an event (in this case even void). this also allows for the component to react on the incoming events in various ways e.g using rxjs.

Comment: Did you consider to use a service?

Comment: actually just came across this: https://angular-book.dev/ch07-03-service-events.html which seems kind of overkill for just 2 sibling components.